# Is there any possibility that deleted data can be recovered back in SAS?

Tags: sas, data-recovery

I am working on production environment. Last day accidentally I made changes to Master dataset permanently while trying to get the sample out of it in work directory. Unfortunately they don't have any backup for this data.

I wanted to execute this:

```
Data work.facttable;
Set Master.facttable(obs=10);
run;
```

instead of this, accidentally I executed the following:

```
data Master.facttable;
set Master.facttable(obs=10);
run;
```

You can clearly see what sort of blunder it was!

Facttable has been building up nearly from 2 long years and it is of 250GB and has millions of rows. Now it has 10 rows and is of 128kb :(

I am very much worried how to recover the data back. It is crucial for the business teams. I have no idea how to proceed to get it back.

I know that SAS doesn't support any rollback options or recovery process. We don't use Audit trail method also.

I am just wondering if there is any way that still we can get the data back in spite of all these.

Details: Dataset is assigned on SPDE Engine. I checked the data files(.dpf) but all were disappeared except yesterday's data file which is of 128kb

Comment: The files may not be visible anymore, but you might be able to roll back at the OS level. For example, if you are running on Windows and filesystem NTFS, you should be able to recover. Unix/Linux also have these options for their filesystems. If you are on the cloud, almost 100% chance that you should be able to recover files

Comment: SAS allows all kinds of recovery - you can backup your drive, for one thing, you can use generation datasets, etc.  You say you don't use the one process that _is_ the rollback option for SAS, so... ?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have exhausted most of the simple options already:

1. Restore from external/OS-level backup
2. Restore from previous generation via the `gennum=` data set option (only available if the `genmax` option was set to 1+ when creating the dataset).
3. Restore from SAS audit trail

I think that leaves you with just 2 options:

4. Rebuild the dataset from the underlying source(s), if you still have them.
5. Engage the services of a professional data recovery company, who might be able to recover some or all of the deleted files, depending on the complexity of your storage environment, and how much of the original 250GB has since been overwritten.

Either way, it sounds as though this may prove to have been an expensive mistake.